# Chart.js how to align grouped bar chart correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have a grouped bar chart use case using Chart.js,
On the X axis I have Months,
On the Y axis, I have stacked bars divided by 2 digit Country codes,

For some reason the bars are not getting aligned properly based on their stack,
The output looks like this using react-chartjs-2 -

[image]

The dataset is like this -

```
{
  labels: ["May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "MY",
      stack: "May",
      backgroundColor: "#f9aabd",
      data: [2]
    },
    {
      label: "ID",
      stack: "May",
      backgroundColor: "#ff980070",
      data: [41]
    },
    {
      label: "MY",
      stack: "June",
      backgroundColor: "#f9aabd",
      data: [2]
    },
    {
      label: "ID",
      stack: "June",
      backgroundColor: "#ff980070",
      data: [64]
    },
    {
      label: "PH",
      stack: "June",
      backgroundColor: "#cce1f3",
      data: [26]
    },
    {
      label: "ID",
      stack: "July",
      backgroundColor: "#ff980070",
      data: [25]
    },
    {
      label: "MY",
      stack: "July",
      backgroundColor: "#f9aabd",
      data: [22]
    },
    {
      label: "PH",
      stack: "July",
      backgroundColor: "#cce1f3",
      data: [3]
    }
  ]
};
```

Following is my code not in reactjs but something similar-
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bartik-4xnkrd?file=/App.tsx

What do I need to change?

Comment: Your image does not look the same as your codepen. I'd suggest using the latest ChartJS version, your code pen uses v2, which is quite old.

Comment: the image is from my application which uses react-chartjs-2, the dataset is the same as codepen, the bars are not aligning properly based on stack

Answer (score 1):

I believe your dataset is wrongly structured.

For stacked bar chart, the structure should be like this:

```json
"datasets": [{
    "label": "MY",
    "stack": "stack1",
    "backgroundColor": "#f9aabd",
    "data": [2, 2, 22]
}, {
    "label": "ID",
    "stack": "stack1",
    "backgroundColor": "#ff980070",
    "data": [41, 64, 25]
}, {
    "label": "PH",
    "stack": "stack1",
    "backgroundColor": "#cce1f3",
    "data": [26, 3, 0]
}]
```

For each "country code" (MY, ID, PH), there should be one object. The values for the months are specified in the data array respectively.

The `stack` attribute specifies name of the stack in the particular month. If you specify more `stack`s, there will be more columns for each of the months.